# a question about chapter9 in EVANS pde

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I'm reading chapter 8 of the pde book written by EVANS.
It's about variation method of pde.
In page 433.
what's the mean of $C_c^\infty(U)$? why the test function $v$ is in this space?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76hou.jpg)

thank you!

Comment: The space $C^\infty_c(U)$ is the space of compactly supported smooth functions on $U$, if this is what you are asking about.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I have calculate as follows:  $\int_U (-V(L_{p_i})_{x_i}+L_z V)dx+\sum L_{p_i} V|_\Omega =0$ ,so $\sum L_{p_i} V|_\Omega =0$ needs to be zero. But why $v$ belongs to $C_c^\infty(U)$?

Comment: I am not on my laptop now. I can reply later.

Comment: look forward your answer :)

Comment: You basically want the boundary integral to vanish, when you do an integration by parts, which is why you require $v$ to have compact support. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I don't really understand why $\sum L_{p_i}V|_{\Omega}=0$ means $v$ have compact support.

Comment: I don't understand. I only see the picture that you have linked to (I don't have Evans' book near me). Are you sure that Evans is deducing that $v$ has compact support? Or is he assuming it? Remember that $v$ is the test function. I have seen arguments like that, and usually one assumes that the test function is of class $C^\infty_c$, and then makes an integration by parts. I hope my comments help a little.

Comment: I understand it ! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ denote the space of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $U$. By definition, the function belonging to this space called a test function. See page 242 of Evans's book for more details.